# numerical solution of ode singularity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I have to solve a nonlinear ode problem: 
\begin{align}
\dot\gamma&=-2(D+0.5A+0.5A\cos\gamma)\sin k \\ 
 -\dot k&=(E-B-B\cos\gamma)+(2D+A+A\cos\gamma)\frac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}\cos k
\end{align}
with the initial condition $\gamma=\pi$ and $k=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.
 My problem is that right hand side of the second equation is infinity for the initial condition, so I cannot use an Euler scheme, for example.

Is there a way to solve it? Can anyone recommend a good textbook on this kind of problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you expect that a solution exists? Did you try perturbations of the initial values?

Answer (score 3):

Playing around with the equations a bit, you can observe that, introducing
\begin{equation}
 X = \cos k\,\sin \gamma,\quad Y = \sin k\,\sin \gamma,\quad Z = \cos \gamma, \tag{1}
\end{equation}
we obtain the following system for $(X,Y,Z)$:
\begin{align}
 \dot{X} &= \phantom{-}\left(E - B(1+Z)\right)\,Y,\\
 \dot{Y} &= -\left(E - B(1+Z)\right)\,X - \left(2 D+A(1+Z)\right)\,Z,\tag{2}\\
 \dot{Z} &= \phantom{-}\left(2 D+A(1+Z)\right)\,Y.
\end{align}
You can easily deduce that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t}\left(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 \right) = 0$, which makes perfect sense, since from $(1)$ follows that 
\begin{equation}
 X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 1.
\end{equation}
In other words, system $(2)$ is naturally confined to the sphere in $(X,Y,Z)$-space.

Admittedly, it looks a bit strange to *increase* the number of model variables, but this serves a purpose. The initial condition $k(0) = -\frac{\pi}{2}, \gamma(0) = \pi$ now translates to
\begin{equation}
 (X(0),Y(0),Z(0)) = (0,0,-1).
\end{equation}
In other words, the initial condition is at the 'south pole' of the sphere. This immediately explains why this initial condition gives infinities when used in the original system: the south pole is a *singular point* in the spherical coordinates $(1)$, see also [MathWorld's lemma on spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).

This suggests a solution to your problem. Note that the system $(2)$ is perfectly well-behaved at $(X,Y,Z) = (0,0,-1)$; the right hand side at this point evaluates to $(0,2 D,0)$. As a matter of fact, system $(2)$ behaves nicely *everywhere*. So, as it turns out, we just made an unfortunate choice of spherical coordinates to study solutions to your original system with this particular initial condition. Let's change our spherical coordinates then! A simple solution is to rotate the singular point, the south pole, away over a $90^\circ$ angle. We can do this by introducing
\begin{equation}
 X = \cos \alpha\, \sin \beta,\quad Y = \cos \beta,\quad Z = \sin \alpha \sin \beta,
\end{equation}
which shifts the 'poles' of the coordinate system to $(0,\pm 1,0)$.
The original system transforms to
\begin{align}
 \dot{\alpha} &= \left(A \cos\alpha + B \sin \alpha\right) \sin\alpha\,\cos\beta + \left((A+2 D)\cos \alpha + (B-E)\sin \alpha\right) \frac{\cos \beta}{\sin\beta},\\
\dot{\beta} &= \left(2 D + A(1+\sin\alpha\,\sin\beta)\right)\sin\alpha + \left(E - B(1+\sin\alpha\sin\beta)\right)\cos\alpha.
\end{align}
The initial condition $(X,Y,Z) = (0,0,-1)$ is now *uniquely* transformed in the initial condition $\alpha = -\frac{\pi}{2}, \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}$. You should have no problems treating this system numerically.